# is there a "dashboard" app that can give me a status summary of all the local git repositories on my filesystem?

Tags: linux, git

I'd like a piece of software that gives me a "dashboard"-like readout for all of my git repositories on my local machine.

I imagine it could tell me statstics like:

- how many files are not yet managed by git
- how many lines of diffs are not yet committed
- how many commits are not yet pushed to each upstream repo
- how many commits I have not yet pulled from upstream

Those last two would be kind of expensive and probably should be calculated in the background.

Something like a compact and pretty version of

```
find $HOME /homes7/contracts/ -name .git -print | while read dir; do 
  d=`dirname $dir` 
  echo $d
  ( cd $d; git status)
  echo 
done
```

Since I have 90+ repos already, this readout needs to be pretty compact.  A GUI would be delicious (and opens up the possibility for increased detail on mouse-over or click), but if none exist I will settle for a command-line tool.  I use Linux exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

I put the status in a text file under `~/status/git-repos.txt`. Here is the shell function I use:

```
function cron_lib_find_git_repo_status_in {
    nice -n 19 find "$*" -name '.git' -print -execdir git status --porcelain --branch \; -execdir git diff --numstat \; |
        grep -v '## master$' &>> "$HOME/status/git-repos.txt"
}
```

Initialize the file and pass it some directories like this:

```
date > "$HOME/status/git-repos.txt"
cron_lib_find_git_repo_status_in "$HOME/src/"
cron_lib_find_git_repo_status_in "$HOME/Dropbox/"
```

Then run that script in a cronjob. The output will contain the branch (excluding boring old `## master`), the modified files, and how many line are added or removed.

It's pretty compact, and it's easy to tell big changes from little changes.

Comment: This is a really good script, but when I run it I realize just how intractable text is when dealing with as many repositories as I have.  I'm beginning to think that a GUI (or HTML variation derived from your techniques) might be the only acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more robust option called `myrepos` that is in the standard repositories.

https://myrepos.branchable.com/

This requires you to register all your repos (unlike the shell script above).

```
$ mr register
Registering git url: git://my-git-url.com/path/to/repo.git in /home/username/.mrconfig
```

You can then use command like `mr status` or `mr diff` to see all the repos. This runs pretty quickly; I can check the status of 64 repositories in nearly half a second with a slow hard drive.

```
$ cd $HOME
$ mr status
<snip>
mr status: finished (64 ok)

real    0m0.674s
user    0m0.268s
sys     0m0.080s
```

The `mr` package supports `git` as well as a variety of other version control systems, but note that you must have at least one remote url, i.e. purely local repositories don't really work. There is a workaround mentioned here if you're curious:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=645965